# PHP class instantiation. To use or not to use the parentheses?

Tags: php, oop, class, instantiation

I've always assumed that - in the absence of constructor parameters - the parentheses (curly brackets) follow the class name when creating a class instance, were optional, and that you could include or exclude them at your own personal whim.

That these two statements were equal:

```
$foo = new bar;
$foo = new bar();
```

Am I right? Or is there some significance to the brackets that I am unaware of?

I know this sounds like a RTM question, but I've been searching for a while (including the entire PHP OOP section) and I can't seem to find a straight answer.

Comment: I know this would be an old answer, but based on **PSR12** coding style: https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/, **"When instantiating a new class, parentheses MUST always be present even when there are no arguments passed to the constructor."**

Answer (score 60, accepted):

They are equivalent. If you are not coding by any [code convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_style), use which you like better. Personally, I like to leave it out, as it is really just clutter to me.

Comment: Agreed. If the constructor doesn't take any parameters I leave them out too

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping this was the case. - Personally I like to always include them. Bad habit from my Java/C# days :)

Comment: ..also, the end part looks like a smirking singing monkey (); laaaa-la

Comment: I'd still argue that it's more conventional to keep the parenthesis! (: friendlier to non-C/C++ background friends coming from C# or Java.

Comment: I would not leave them out since it is still a *function call* - a call to the constructor method.It is also not allowed to omit the `()` when you call other functions or methods which takes no required parameters. So why should I do this with constructor? `new Foo()` instead of `new Foo` is better for readability IMHO.

Comment: You can enforce using `new` with braces using https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer/blob/2.3/src/Fixer/Operator/NewWithBracesFixer.php.

Comment: It's not really a function call - the constructor, if it exists, is called automatically by the system, but not directly. The return value from new is the new instance, it isn't anything returned from the constructor.

Answer (score 6):

`$foo = new bar()` would be useful over `$foo = new bar` if you were passing arguments to the constructor. For example:

```
class bar {

    public $user_id;

    function __construct( $user_id ) {
        $this->user_id = $user_id
    }
}
```

-

```
$foo = new bar( $user_id );
```

Aside from that, and as already mentioned in the accepted answer, there is no difference.