# Php: Parentheses when creating new object?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Instantiate a class with or without parentheses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873111/instantiate-a-class-with-or-without-parentheses)

This is a minor quibble, but is there any reason to prefer

```
$obj = new SomeClass();
```

over

```
$obj = new SomeClass;
```

I prefer the latter because I like how it looks, and it saves you a couple of characters.  On the downside, it goes against conventions and makes it slightly harder to come back and add an argument later.

Anyone have a compelling argument for either, or is this pure semantics?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Doesn't matter as long as your code is consistent, conventional & clear.

Answer (score 2):

The parentheses are for passing arguments into __construct. Just keep one style, and follow it, unless you have to pass arguments into classes.

Of course, you could just go for the new class; format until you need new classtwo($one, $two). That might be a little inconsistent at first, but it'll make sense in the long run.

Though, pure semantics. Just that.