# Creating default object from empty value in PHP?

Tags: php

I see this error only after upgrading my PHP environment to PHP 5.4 and beyond. The error points to this line of code:

Error:

> Creating default object from empty value

Code:

```
$res->success = false;
```

Do I first need to declare my `$res` object?

Comment: How/Where are you initiating `$res ` ?

Comment: @NAVEED [There](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/d8507d4f582997ae3efe074f54900af2936835e6/Zend/zend_execute.c#L593).

Comment: I had this but it was because the visibility of the property on my parent object was private.

Answer (score 747, accepted):

Your new environment may have `E_STRICT` warnings [enabled in `error_reporting`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) for PHP versions <= 5.3.x, or simply have `error_reporting` set to at least `E_WARNING` with PHP versions >= 5.4. That error is triggered when `$res` is `NULL` or not yet initialized:

```
$res = NULL;
$res->success = false; // Warning: Creating default object from empty value
```

PHP will report a different error message if `$res` is already initialized to some value but is not an object:

```
$res = 33;
$res->success = false; // Warning: Attempt to assign property of non-object
```

In order to comply with `E_STRICT` standards prior to PHP 5.4, or the normal `E_WARNING` error level in PHP >= 5.4, assuming you are trying to create a generic object and assign the property `success`, you need to declare `$res` as an object of `stdClass` in the global namespace:

```
$res = new \stdClass();
$res->success = false;
```

Comment: @Tomas Of course you may need to check, but that isn't relevant to the question. This is about how to properly instantiate a `stdClass`. It is the responsibility of the developer to be sure an existing object or scalar isn't being overwritten if the variable already exists.

Comment: You shoud check whether the object already exists: `if (!isset($res)) $res = new stdClass();`. Otherwise, this code is not an equivalent replacement for the "old PHP" implicit object creation.

Comment: @Tomas Do we need to do this again? The mods cleaned up the comment thread last time because it added little of value.  There is no "old PHP" implicit object creation. It was always an error and always issued a warning, just that it was changed from E_STRICT to E_WARNING in 5.4, so some people never encountered it not having paid attention to E_STRICT.

Comment: @Tomas I'm no PHP expert, but given the error the OP reported, don't you know that `$res` is undefined in this case, thus eliminating the need for the check you're proposing?

Comment: @PeterAlfvin Interesting, thanks. I wondered what sparked this.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin it was not defined **in that one particular run**! But in different run, *at the exact same place in the code*, the object might be already defined! This is mistake in thinking people often make and that's the reason I try to emphasize that.

Comment: Michael, the implicit object creation always was and is still present even in 5.4. And BTW In PHP < 5.3 it was neither E_STRICT nor E_WARNING. And BTW, mods have restored the comment and I was told to tone it down, that's why I re-posted it.

Comment: @tomas Oh, ok, I _think_ I get what you mean. It seems odd that you/Michael can't get to closure on this. BTW, this exchange has led me to realize that italics<bold<allcaps in terms of "strength" and that while allcaps=shouting and italics=politeEmphasis, bold is in a middle ground where the acceptability is questionable. :-)

Comment: Why do you use `$res = new stdClass();` instead of the shorter version `$res = new stdClass;`?

Comment: @Pacerier It is a matter of style. Use whatever is your team's agreed-upon convention. I always use them because I don't like class constructors without args to be treated differently than those with, and I don't want `stdClass` to be treated differently than any class I define myself. [Here you will find one suggestion, then the opposite suggestion in a linked duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9325491/when-to-add-brackets-after-new-class-name).  It's only up to style.

Comment: @Pacerier [And another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873111/instantiate-a-class-with-or-without-parentheses)  `stdClass` calls no constructor, so if you don't want to think of it like a method call, omit the `()`. I would not omit them though for consistency with userdef classes

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, Well, omit them and still have consistency with userdef classes by omitting them in userdef classes too.

Comment: @Pacerier No, that's inconsistent between classes which have constructor params and those which do not. It doesn't matter- this is a question of opinion and style and I'm not going to argue it in the comments.

Comment: This grammar is very confusing.

"Your new environment may have E_STRICT warnings enabled in error_reporting if it is PHP <= 5.3, or if simply have error_reporting set to at least E_WARNING with PHP 5.4+.

Comment: In my case, i spelt the object variable wrongly. Watch out for that!

Answer (score 68):

This message has been `E_STRICT` for PHP <= 5.3. Since PHP 5.4, it was unluckilly changed to `E_WARNING`. Since `E_WARNING` messages are useful, you don't want to disable them completely.

To get rid of this warning, you must use this code:

```
if (!isset($res)) 
    $res = new stdClass();

$res->success = false;
```

This is **fully equivalent replacement**. It assures exactly the same thing which PHP is silently doing - unfortunatelly with warning now - implicit object creation. You should always check if the object already exists, unless you are absolutely sure that it doesn't. The code provided by Michael is no good in general, because in some contexts the object might sometimes be already defined at the same place in code, depending on circumstances.

Comment: @carlosvini, This will give you `Undefined variable: res`.

Comment: @Pacerier You are right, the best you can do is: $res = isset($res) ? $res : new stdClass(); -- which was the reason i didn't have E_NOTICE enabled 6 months ago, since it's too damn verbose.

Answer (score 18):

Simply,

```
    $res = (object)array("success"=>false); // $res->success = bool(false);
```

Or you could instantiate classes with:

```
    $res = (object)array(); // object(stdClass) -> recommended

    $res = (object)[];      // object(stdClass) -> works too

    $res = new \stdClass(); // object(stdClass) -> old method
```

and fill values with:

```
    $res->success = !!0;     // bool(false)

    $res->success = false;   // bool(false)

    $res->success = (bool)0; // bool(false)
```

More infos:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php#language.types.object.casting

Comment: why is new stdClass() considered an "old" method?  Are the others somehow better?

Comment: Its simply from old php version

Comment: in my case `$this->route->uri  = new stdClass();` is not working for me, I still have the warning. Note : `$this->route` is existing.

Comment: Maybe this is not compatible with new versions of php ? Which version you used ?

Answer (score 8):

If you put "@" character begin of the line then PHP doesn't show any warning/notice for this line. For example:

```
$unknownVar[$someStringVariable]->totalcall = 10; // shows a warning message that contains: Creating default object from empty value
```

For preventing this warning for this line you must put "@" character begin of the line like this:

```
@$unknownVar[$someStringVariable]->totalcall += 10; // no problem. created a stdClass object that name is $unknownVar[$someStringVariable] and created a properti that name is totalcall, and it's default value is 0.
$unknownVar[$someStringVariable]->totalcall += 10; // you don't need to @ character anymore.
echo $unknownVar[$someStringVariable]->totalcall; // 20
```

I'm using this trick when developing. I don't like disable all warning messages becouse if you don't handle warnings correctly then they will become a big error in future.

Comment: @ does prevent warnings by suppressing it, looks ok for as long as you have manageable code. But if your code grows into something bigger and you ran into an issue, you'll somehow regret using this. You'll find yourself looking for all those "@" for a  warning you'd want to unhide because temporarily it has served its purpose thinking that you have actually fixed the issue when in reality it has been talking to you and you just wouldn't listen.

Comment: I know already. This is short and fast answer. There are lots of solution for this.

Comment: awesome! May I politely beg to disagree though, hiding the error is not really fixing the problem (as what Ramy Nasr commented as well).

Comment: This workaround is the only workin for me on php 7.2.

Answer (score 6):

Try this if you have array and add objects to it.

```
$product_details = array();

foreach ($products_in_store as $key => $objects) {
  $product_details[$key] = new stdClass(); //the magic
  $product_details[$key]->product_id = $objects->id; 
   //see new object member created on the fly without warning.
}
```

This sends **ARRAY** of **Objects** for later use~!

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! This is what helped get the job done. I needed to tell PHP step-by-step what each element was. Thanks for reminding me not to code lazy lol.

Answer (score 4):

In PHP 7 anonymous objects can be created this way:

```
$res = new class {
    public $success = false;
};
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.anonymous.php
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ab774707a8219c0f35bdba49cc84228b580b52ee

Answer (score 2):

1. First think you should create object
   $res = new \stdClass();
2. then assign object with key and value thay 
   $res->success = false;

Comment: (I don't understand `thay`.) Where you want a line break after some contents, append two blank spaces to the visible contents of the line before the break-to-be.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from PHP 7 you can use a null coalescing operator to create a object when the variable is null.

```
$res = $res ?? new \stdClass();
$res->success = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_STRICT);
```

Comment: Thanks. this is use full when you are using third-party libraries such as nusoap and don't want / can't change the source. In that case you can change error_reporting to **E_STRICT** level just before requiring other source files.

Comment: Although I just added this to the top of nusoap to fix my problem.

Comment: Huh? The code here disables all error reporting except `E_STRICT` errors, including suppressing messages for fatal errors. That's not a reasonable suggestion to solve this particular warning, and what's more is something you pretty much never ever want to do. Why 5 people upvoted this, I have no clue.

Comment: This is super bad! use `ini_set('error_reporting', -1);` while debugging, but don't use the above, like ever.

Comment: Ok, so you fix a problem by hiding this one ? Not sure your code will work as expected...

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem and this seem to solve the problem. You just need to initialize the $res object to a class . Suppose here the class name is test.

```
class test
{
   //You can keep the class empty or declare your success variable here
}
$res = new test();
$res->success = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to get this error is to type (a) below, meaning to type (b)

*(a)* `$this->my->variable`

*(b)* `$this->my_variable`

Trivial, but very easily overlooked and hard to spot if you are not looking for it.

Comment: How is this related to the original question? There was no mix-up between `_` and `->`

Answer (score 0):

You may need to check if variable declared and has correct type.

```
if (!isset($res) || !is_object($res)) {
    $res = new \stdClass();
    // With php7 you also can create an object in several ways.
    // Object that implements some interface.
    $res = new class implements MyInterface {};
    // Object that extends some object.
    $res = new class extends MyClass {};
} 

$res->success = true;
```

See [PHP anonymous classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.anonymous.php).

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
$user = (object) null;
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem while trying to add a variable to an object returned from an API.  I was iterating through the data with a foreach loop.

```
foreach ( $results as $data ) {
    $data->direction = 0;
}
```

This threw the "Creating default object from empty value" Exception in Laravel.

I fixed it with a very small change.

```
foreach ( $results as &$data ) {
    $data->direction = 0;
}
```

By simply making $data a reference.

I hope that helps somebody a it was annoying the hell out of me!

Answer (score 0):

This is a warning which I faced in PHP 7, the easy fix to this is by initializing the variable before using it

```
$myObj=new \stdClass();
```

Once you have intialized it then you can use it for objects

```
 $myObj->mesg ="Welcome back - ".$c_user;
```

Answer (score -1):

no you do not .. it will create it when you add the success value to the object.the default class is inherited if you do not specify one.

Comment: Though it will return the Strict standards message... it is simply good practise to create the object manually first, and while PHP is relatively tolerant of shoddy coding practise, you shouldn't ignore doing things correctly.

Comment: understood, i was just answering the question with a simple yes or no, not defining or defending best practices :)

Answer (score -1):

This problem is caused because your are assigning to an instance of object which is not initiated. For eg:

**Your case:**

```
$user->email = 'exy@gmail.com';
```

**Solution:**

```
$user = new User;
$user->email = 'exy@gmail.com';
```

Comment: aren't you assuming that the class "User" exists? which it may not and now it'll generate a different error?

Comment: Actually i did not created an instance of the User object so i got an error. But after creating an instance. It worked.. its a generic problem with OOPs concept :)

Comment: well, actually the real problem is that your example assumes the user class to be defined, this isn't a generic problem of object orientation, its a key requirement ;)

Comment: I'd rather put a generic "stdClass" replacing the premise implying "User".

Answer (score -12):

I put the following at the top of the faulting PHP file and the error was no longer display:

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
```