# Creating default object from empty value, how to define a value

Tags: php, wordpress, warnings

I am getting an warning message in my Wordpress :

> "Creating default object from empty value in
>   /home/forthemde/public_html/wp-content/themes/mayadeep/admin/admin.php
>   on line 225"

Here the code on `admin.php` and:

```
 function upfw_setup_theme_options(){
     $up_options_db = get_option('up_themes_'.UPTHEMES_SHORT_NAME);
     global $up_options;
     //Check if options are stored properly
     if( isset($up_options_db) && is_array($up_options_db) ):
         //Check array to an object
         foreach ($up_options_db as $k => $v) {
                 $up_options -> {$k} = $v;
         }
     else:
         do_action('upfw_theme_activation');
     endif;
 }
 add_action('upfw_theme_init','upfw_setup_theme_options',10);
 add_action('upfw_admin_init','upfw_setup_theme_options',100);
```

Line 225 is here:

```
 $up_options -> {$k} = $v;
```

I try to fix by myself, but no result. Please help me, really appreciate for any help.

Regards.

Comment: Can I suggest just typecasting `$up_options_db` to an object? `$up_options = (object) $up_options_db;` - Does that do as you want?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900701/creating-default-object-from-empty-value-in-php

Comment: Hi, Jothi Kannan. How can I do that? Which part I should to change? Really appreciate for your help.

Comment: @AnabeleRosemary you can do it by using blockquote in the editor

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too, recently, but this worked for me:

Just added `$up_options = new stdClass();` after `global $up_options;`

Best regards,
http://shubhinfotech.com http://c-worx.com

Comment: Ran into this issue recently. This worked for me. Thanks!