# declaring a object inside a class, giving some weird warning

Tags: php, class, object, declaration

I am trying to declare an object of type `Spell` in my class `Game` like this:

```
<?php
require 'Spell.php';

class Game
{

    public $Name;
    public $Spell;

    function Game()
    {
        $Name[0] = 0;
        $Spell = new Spell;

    }
```

This is returning this warning:

> "Warning: Creating default object from empty value in"

and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
class Game
{

    public $Name = array();
    public $Spell;

    function Game()
    {
        $this->Name[0] = 0;
        $this->Spell = new Spell();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
function Game()
{
    $this->Name = [ 0 ];
    $this->Spell = new Spell();
}
```

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900701/creating-default-object-from-empty-value-in-php) for more details on the error.