# Joomla 1.5 and Wincache

Tags: php, joomla

I make the integration of Wincache with Joomla 1.5, but i see often, in php_errors this:

PHP Warning:  Creating default object from empty value in joomla.php on line 136

The code is this:

```
$session =& JFactory::getSession();
$session->set('user', $instance);

$storage = $session->_store;
$session_data = $storage->readSessionData($session->getId());
/*136*/ $session_data->guest    = $instance->get('guest');
$session_data->username = $instance->get('username');
```

I think that I need to declare the object but i don't know how...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

these are warnings.

If they do not affect your site usability, you may turn them of using the backend.

Go to  Global Configuration.

In the server tab (If I remember well) there is something like Error Reporting.

Turn it off by setting it to none.

Comment: I understand that I can disable the warnings of php, but I prefer to solve the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Joomla 1.5 is past end of life and does not really work perfectly in current version of PHP (since it was written to support 4.4.7 an... so a lot of things that didn't used to generate warnings are going to generate warnings if you have modern PHP and it sometimes can really not be worth the effort.  Does $instance actually exist?

Comment: Yes, i altro try this very similar solution but nothing...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900701/creating-default-object-from-empty-value-in-php

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!
$session_data was empty in some circoustance so this generate the problem:

```
$session_data = $storage->readSessionData($session->getId());
```

For solve it, simple add:

```
if (! $storage->readSessionData($session->getId()) ){$session_data = new stdClass();}
```

Thanks to all!