# php with aigaion2 after upgrade to ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, codeigniter, web, interface, bibliography

I have been using the web based bibliography management system `aigaion2` for some years, accumulating thousands of references  & linked pdf files. However after upgrading from `ubuntu 12.04` to `14.04` - with a change in the version of PHP - this fails to give me a log-in screen.  There are 2 warning messages;

I am at a loss how to deal with this - does anybody have this working with a recent PHP version or might have any idea how to fix this. From the aigaion website, it seems the package does not have any active maintainers any longer.

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Creating default object from empty value

Filename: gettext/gettext.inc

Line Number: 195

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /data1/aigaion2/codeigniter/libraries/Exceptions.php:166)

Filename: helpers/url_helper.php

Line Number: 541
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to use Aigaion too. I got some errors.
You will find new release here :
On source.forge : [Source.Forge](http://sourceforge.net/p/aigaion/git/ci/master/tree/webserver/)
This release replaces old php "commands" to some new ones
eregi to preg_replace
split to explode, etc.

It seems that a 2.5 beta exists :
[Release 2.5 beta](https://github.com/maiers/Aigaion)
I'll check today.

For your problem, I did a small update in the module aigaion2\aigaionengine\libraries\gettext\gettext.inc ligne 193

```
function _bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, $codeset) {
  global $text_domains;
  /*
   * MVT 150505 : Add !isset due to warning errors
   * It is a temporary features. It should be better
   * to migrate to a new PHP Release
   * Tested with Xamp / Php 5.6.8
   * I did this patch in order to use Aigaion with no errors
   * I don't have a large knowledge in PHP. Sorry
   */
  if (!isset($text_domains[$domain]))
        $text_domains[$domain] = new stdClass();
  $text_domains[$domain]->codeset = $codeset;

}
```

I found an answer here :
[Empty objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900701/creating-default-object-from-empty-value-in-php)

This should be a little patch...

Comment: many thanks for your comments - I did look  at version 2.5 some time ago (tried to install)  - which seems to be dated 3 years ago - however it did not help

Answer (score 0):

further development of aigaion is being made at http://github.com/aigaion. This verison is compatible with php7, besides not fully updated.