# Creating default object from empty value in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have encountered the following error when I try and run my code

**Creating default object from empty value**

the line of code in question is :

```
   $this->layout->content = View::make('search', array('table' => $table));
```

I am following a tutorial located here : http://wern-ancheta.com/blog/2014/08/10/using-datatables-with-laravel/

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I'd imagine you're following the tutorial too literally. `$this` can only be used the context of a class. If you're not sure what that means, this tutorial might be slightly above your current level..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating default object from empty value in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900701/creating-default-object-from-empty-value-in-php)

Comment: You shall declare your layout first in controller. You should set the value of ```protected $layout``` to the name of view you want to set as layout for this controller i.e. ```protected $layout = 'layouts.master';``` then it will get resolved to actual view when the controller gets instantiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have layout defined, declare it:

```
protected $layout = 'layout.default';
```

and then use

```
$this->layout->content = View::make('search', array('table' => $table));
```

Or another way:

```
$layout = new stdClass();
$layout->layout = new stdClass();

$layout->layout->content = View::make('search', array('table' => $table));
```