# Creating default object from empty value ( stdClass? )

Tags: php, function, object, default, stdclass

The script run good, but only when I fetching out the groups of the user, it's says:

> SteamUser.php (132): Creating default object from empty value

```
    function getProfileData() {

    //Set Base URL for the query:
    if(empty($this->vanityURL)) {
        $base = "http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/{$this->userID}/?xml=1";
    } else {
        $base = "http://steamcommunity.com/id/{$this->vanityURL}/?xml=1";
    }

    try {
        $content = SteamUtility::fetchURL($base);
        if ($content) {
            $parsedData = new SimpleXMLElement($content);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        //echo "Whoops! Something went wrong!\n\nException Info:\n" . $e . "\n\n";
        return null;
    }

    if(!empty($parsedData)) {   
        $this->steamID64 = (string)$parsedData->steamID64;
        $this->steamID = (string)$parsedData->steamID;
        $this->stateMessage = (string)$parsedData->stateMessage;
        $this->visibilityState = (int)$parsedData->visibilityState;
        $this->privacyState = (string)$parsedData->privacyState;

        $this->avatarIcon = (string)$parsedData->avatarIcon;
        $this->avatarMedium = (string)$parsedData->avatarMedium;
        $this->avatarFull = (string)$parsedData->avatarFull;

        $this->vacBanned = (int)$parsedData->vacBanned;
        $this->tradeBanState = (string)$parsedData->tradeBanState;
        $this->isLimitedAccount = (string)$parsedData->isLimitedAccount;

        $this->onlineState = (string)$parsedData->onlineState;
        $this->inGameServerIP = (string)$parsedData->inGameServerIP;

        //If their account is public, get that info:
        if($this->privacyState == "public") {
            $this->customURL = (string)$parsedData->customURL;
            $this->memberSince = (string)$parsedData->memberSince;

            $this->steamRating = (float)$parsedData->steamRating;
            $this->hoursPlayed2Wk = (float)$parsedData->hoursPlayed2Wk;

            $this->headline = (string)$parsedData->headline;
            $this->location = (string)$parsedData->location;
            $this->realname = (string)$parsedData->realname;
            $this->summary = (string)$parsedData->summary;
        }

        //If they're in a game, grab that info:
        if($this->onlineState == "in-game") {
            $this->inGameInfo = array();
            $this->inGameInfo["gameName"] = (string)$parsedData->inGameInfo->gameName;
            $this->inGameInfo["gameLink"] = (string)$parsedData->inGameInfo->gameLink;
            $this->inGameInfo["gameIcon"] = (string)$parsedData->inGameInfo->gameIcon;
            $this->inGameInfo["gameLogo"] = (string)$parsedData->inGameInfo->gameLogo;
            $this->inGameInfo["gameLogoSmall"] = (string)$parsedData->inGameInfo->gameLogoSmall;
        } 

        //Any weblinks listed in their profile:
        if(!empty($parsedData->weblinks)) {
            $this->weblinks = array();

            $i = 0;
            foreach ($parsedData->weblinks->weblink as $weblink) {
                $this->weblinks[$i]->title = (string)$weblink->title;
                $this->weblinks[$i]->link = (string)$weblink->link;
                $i++;
            }
        }   

  if(!empty($parsedData->groups)) {
            $this->groups = array();

            $i = 0;
            foreach ($parsedData->groups->group as $group) {
```

> **$this->groups[$i]->groupID64 = (string)$group->groupID64;** // row 132 in script

```
                $this->groups[$i]->groupName = (string)$group->groupName;
                $this->groups[$i]->groupURL = (string)$group->groupURL;
                $this->groups[$i]->headline = (string)$group->headline;
                $this->groups[$i]->summary = (string)$group->summary;

                $this->groups[$i]->avatarIcon = (string)$group->avatarIcon;
                $this->groups[$i]->avatarMedium = (string)$group->avatarMedium;
                $this->groups[$i]->avatarFull = (string)$group->avatarFull;

                $this->groups[$i]->memberCount = (string)$group->memberCount;
                $this->groups[$i]->membersInChat = (string)$group->membersInChat;
                $this->groups[$i]->membersInGame = (string)$group->membersInGame;
                $this->groups[$i]->membersOnline = (string)$group->membersOnline; 

                $i++;
            }

        }                    

    }
}
  .
```

.
.
I already tried to using associative arrays, but didn't work; maybe with doing it all new. -_-

So, I can't set error_reporting(0) or ini_set at all.

I also used new stdClass() as a try. But I didn't get this running too.

Comment: `set error_reporting(0)` is not solving any problem. It hides the problem. But the problem is still lurking there unsolved. You should never need to do that (actually you should rather try the opposite and enable as many warnings reported as possible)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating default object from empty value in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900701/creating-default-object-from-empty-value-in-php)

Comment: I writed an answer. Did it help? Would you like more help? Could you fix the issue?

Comment: I'm sorry! Yeah it worked well! Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create an array.

```
$this->groups = array();
```

But in this array you donot create any object. You just use this array's elements (thoes are not initialized) as objects. You should add this line before your 132. row.

```
$this->groups[$i] = new Group();
```

Or something similar.
If you do not have Group class you should try

```
$this->groups[$i] = new stdClass();
```