# Avoiding warning when creating attribute in PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php

PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser's way of creating an attribute

```
file_get_html("http://google.com")->find('body')->bgcolor = '&675432';
```

on PHP 5.6.13 causes a warning

```
Creating default object from empty value
```

.

Is there some way to create an attribute without such a warning without changing the error reporting level or defacing the code as per [Creating default object from empty value in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900701/creating-default-object-from-empty-value-in-php) ?

That defacement is having to create an object manually where the object doe not exist, but in the example above, it does.

EDIT: var_dump(file_get_html("http://google.com")->find('body'));

gives

array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(simple_html_dom_node)#18 (9) {
    ["nodetype"]=>
    int(1)
    ["tag"]=>
    string(4) "body"
    ["attr"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["bgcolor"]=>
      string(4) "#fff"
    }
    ["children"]=>
    array(6) {
      [0]=>
      object(simple_html_dom_node)#19 (9) {
        ["nodetype"]=>
        int(1)
        ["tag"]=>
        string(6) "script"
        ["attr"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["children"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["nodes"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          object(simple_html_dom_node)#20 (9) {
            ["nodetype"]=>
            int(3)
            ["tag"]=>
            string(4) "text"
            ["attr"]=>
            array(0) {
            }
            ["children"]=>
            array(0) {
            }
            ["nodes"]=>
            array(0) {
            }
            ["parent"]=>
            *RECURSION*
            ["_"]=>
            array(1) {
              [4]=>
              string(16) "***noise*** 1007"
            }
            ["tag_start"]=>
            int(0)
            ["dom":"simple_html_dom_node":private]=>
            object(simple_html_dom)#1 (23) {
              ["root"]=>
              object(simple_html_dom_node)#2 (9) {
                ["nodetype"]=>
                int(5)
                ["tag"]=>
                string(4) "root"
                ["attr"]=>
                array(0) {
                }
                ["children"]=>
                array(2) {
                  [0]=>
                  object(simple_html_dom_node)#3 (9) {
                    ["nodetype"]=>
                    int(6)
                    ["tag"]=>
                    string(7) "unknown"
                    ["attr"]=>
                    array(0) {
                    }
                    ["children"]=>
                    array(0) {
                    }
                    ["nodes"]=>
                    array(0) {
                    }
                    ["parent"]=>
                    *RECURSION*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure by what you mean by "defacing code" but the answer is in the link you posted.

If $e is not an object, you need to declare it as one.  This is done with:

`$e = new stdClass()`

You could also do `$e = (object) []`. Which essentially does the same thing, you type cast a blank array to an object.

Comment: Thanks, but the answer is not in the link I posted wince the question requires not defacing the code, and that answer defaces :-)

Comment: "If $e is not an object" Thanks, but I have improved the example to show how this does not apply.

Comment: ChrisJJ, you wouldn't be getting that warning if it was an object.  Do a `var_dump(file_get_html("http://google.com")->find['body'])` and post it as an update to your Q.

Comment: Will do. And oops, my find[] should be find() of course.

Answer (score 0):

```
file_get_html("http://google.com")->find('body',0)->bgcolor = '&675432';
```

find() was returning an array. Whilst I cannot see how this is an 'empty value' as per the error message, with ",0" added, find() returns an element, as is required by "->".