# wp forum plugin error after move to another host

Tags: php, wordpress

I decided to move to dreamhost since mediatemple is too expensive for me. i moved everything over but get one error with the forum plugin. i moved from 5.4 to php 5.6 fast cgi. when i changed to php 5.5 its still the same reporting

a php error says above the forum page:

Warning: Creating default object from empty value in `wp-content/plugins/simple-forum/library/sf-database.php` on line 2094

the referred code snippet is:

```
# sf_filter_new_post_list()
#
# Support: Returns filtered list that current user has permissions to
#   $recordset: Full list of forum/topics
# ------------------------------------------------------------------
function sf_filter_new_post_list($recordset)
{
if(!$recordset) return '';

$rlist = array();
$x = 0;

foreach($recordset as $record)
{
$rlist[$x]->forum_id=$record->forum_id;
$rlist[$x]->topic_id=$record->topic_id;
$x++;
}
return $rlist;
}
```

the exact line says:

```
$rlist[$x]->forum_id=$record->forum_id;
```

how to solve this? can anyone help please.

Comment: check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900701/creating-default-object-from-empty-value-in-php

Comment: yeash im somehow a noob. i get that it has to do with error reporting but need exact instruction for me to solve this. they say put this code in etc. where? which file?

Answer (score 1):

As described in this question [Creating default object from empty value in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900701/creating-default-object-from-empty-value-in-php) from PHP 5.4+ the error is triggered when your `$rlist[$x]` is empty or not initialized.

So try initializing your array element with empty StdClass instance, and than adding value to your object

```
foreach($recordset as $record){
   $rlist[$x] = new StdClass();
   $rlist[$x]->forum_id = $record->forum_id;
   $rlist[$x]->topic_id = $record->topic_id;
   $x++;
}
```

Comment: okey i downgraded to 5.3 for now but my host will probably soon upgrade all systems to 5.6. i will then come back to this solution i guess. thanks for your help for now.

Comment: hey @diego i changed the lines as you said it it gave this error with ?> in the line: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /wp-content/plugins/simple-forum/library/sf-database.php on line 4127