# Creating default object from empty value warning, how to fix?

Tags: fuelphp

I have this simple method in one of my objects:

```
public function action_buddy($name = 'buddy')
{
    $this->response->body = View::forge('hello', array(
        'name' => $name,
    ));
}
```

But I always get this warning and can't proceed futher:

> Fuel\Core\PhpErrorException [ Warning ]: Creating default object from
>   empty value

From this line:

```
$this->response->body = View::forge('hello', array(
```

How can I fix this warning?

p.s. I was following this tutorial http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-the-fuel-php-framework--net-21334

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900701/creating-default-object-from-empty-value-in-php

Comment: As @Alex pointed out it is because `$this->response` contains a `null` value.

`$this->response` will only exist if something has created it.

What is your controller extending? Is there a `before()` method that sets up `$this->response`?

Comment: My point is: there is the same question with chosen answer. That's the only thing I wanted to say.

Comment: As Uru said, there could be a parent controller, that sets up `$this->response` in `before` (or it should). So this could be a different question, though I also presume there's very little research effort in this question.
@Tachi, as you can see, the exception is a `PhpErrorException`, so this is most probably NOT FuelPHP related.

Answer (score 0):

the tutorial you are using is really old, a lot of user also asked on that part. Anyway to answer your question, here it is:

```
    return View::forge('hello', array(
        'name' => $name,
    ));
```

OR

```
    // create the layout view
    $view = View::forge('hello');

    //local view variables, lazy rendering
    $view->name = $name;

    // return the view object to the Request
    return $view;
```

dont forget on your **fuel/app/config/routes.php**   please comment

```
   //'hello(/:name)?' => array('welcome/hello', 'name' => 'hello'),
```

If you got bored with that tutorial, try this

http://ucf.github.io/fuelphp-crash-course/

+1 on your question, Enjoy Fuelphp!