# PHP Array Warning: Creating default object from empty value

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have taken values from a MySQL query into an array so that I can sort them.  It all works well except I am getting lots of errors

```
 Warning: Creating default object from empty value
```

This is so that I can sort the array based on post_id and quality

```
$count = 0;
$searcharticles = new stdClass();
$postid = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result1) ) {

    $postid     = $row->ID;
    $title      = $row->post_title;
    $titlescore = $row->titlescore;
    $quality    = $row->quality;

    $searcharticles->$postid->post_id =$postid;
    $searcharticles->$postid->title =$title;
    $searcharticles->$postid->titlescore = $titlescore;
    $searcharticles->$postid->quality =$quality;

$count ++;
}
```

Some posts on Stackexchange indicated that I should add in 
    $searcharticles = new stdClass();

But this has not solved the problem

I am looking to remove the errors and not just suppress the warnings.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating default object from empty value in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900701/creating-default-object-from-empty-value-in-php)

Comment: No I tried that first.  That is whi I tried adding the $searcharticles = new stdClass(); and $postid = new stdClass(); lines to the code.

Comment: Yes $postid is an integer.I have changed the code to $postid=0; but the error is the same

Comment: What type of structure are you trying to create? Creating object properties named by the integer `$postid` is confusing. If `$searcharticles` is to be a collection, it should be an array of objects, such that you are creating `$searcharticles[$postid]->title = $title` for example.

Comment: ... Which then requires that you initialize each array item to a new stdClass first: `$searcharticles[$postid] = new stdClass();` and instead of creating `$searcharticles` as a stdClass, create it as an `array()`.

Comment: I am trying to combine 4 different MySQL queries in a separate array with postid as the common identifier between the queries.  I then calculate a weighted average score based on the 4 queries and then sort on the combined score.  It works well but is throwing these errors.

Comment: The problem is the multiple chaining. Do `$searcharticles->$postid = new StdClass` before you do any `$searcharticles->$postid->foo = "bar"`

Comment: @Jonty5817 Is the query you have above expected to produce multiple results? If so, make `$searcharticles` an array _indexed_ by `$postid` as in my comment.

Comment: Gordon that solved the problem.  Many thanks.

Comment: @Michael Berkowski.  I think that that is a good suggestion for improving my object structure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You get the warning

> Warning: Creating default object from empty value

because you do

```
$searcharticles->$postid->post_id = $postid;
```

Your `$searcharticles` is a StdClass. You assign the property `$postId` and then immediately chain off another property `post_id`, which forces PHP to create a new default object.

To avoid it, put this before the chained method calls:

```
$searcharticles->$postid = new StdClass;
$searcharticles->$postid->post_id =$postid;
$searcharticles->$postid->title =$title;
$searcharticles->$postid->titlescore = $titlescore;
$searcharticles->$postid->quality =$quality;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problem is not $searcharticles, could be $row.

Try

```
$searcharticles = new stdClass; AND $row = new stdClass;
```

Good luck!