# Warning: Creating default object from empty value PHP

Tags: php, oop

I know there are several similar questions like mine. But I've gone through most of them but found only similar answers that don't solve my situation:

I am creating a PHP website using OOP and wish to edit a record from the database. Here is the link to `edit_short.php`:

```
<td><a href="edit_short.php?id=<?php echo $short->id; ?>">Edit</a></td>
```

This record id is received in `edit_short.php`  as follows:

```
<?php
require_once("short.php");
$id = null;
// $short = new stdClass(); **I was told to use this but it didn't work**

if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
  $id=$_GET['id'];
  $short = Short::find_by_id($id);
}

if (isset($_POST['edit_short_btn'])) { 
  $short->title = $_POST['title']; //the error is on this line
  $short->short_text = $_POST['short_text'];
}
```

Here is my the relevant section of my `Short` class:

```
public static function find_by_id($id=0) {
  global $database;
  $result_array = self::find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM short WHERE id=$id LIMIT 1");
  return !empty($result_array) ? array_shift($result_array) : false;
}
```

Some answers on stackoverflow and other websites i was told to define `$short` as an object of the `stdClass()` but that doesn't apply here since `$short` object in my case must be of the `Short` class.

Thanks you very much for any help..

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

[Don't believe it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38297105/1011527)

Comment: FYI, your code is subject to SQL injection attacks, and likely XSS as well.  Use prepared/parameterized queries in your SQL.  Use `htmlspecialchars()` or similar when injecting data into an HTML context.

Comment: just put a @ in front of that line, it's the answer to every error in php ;)

Comment: Is there any particular reason for defining find_by_id as a static function ?

Comment: You are assigning the return of `find_by_id()` to `$short` which is an array or `false` and then trying to use `$short` as an object: `$short->title`.  So it appears, that you have no idea what you are doing...

Comment: what exactly does this `find_by_sql()` function do?

Comment: `$short` probably isn't defined. Make sure you're hitting the first if, which you may not be able to since you really can't/shouldn't mix GET/POST.

Comment: Yes. find_by_id() doesn't belong to a particular object of the class. It can be used even when there is no instance of the Short class

Comment: Agreeing to @JayBlanchard and @Brad... if you only use a single instance of that `Short` class, it would be `$short::title = ...` and the like. `$short` refers to an object instance, which you do not create; you would have to do `$anything = new Short();` before.

Comment: In other words, either access it by a single object (`::`) or create an instance (`new` and `->`).

Comment: `$anything = new Short();` would create an entirely new object right? But am editing here so i need the attributes of the object am editing

Comment: Which you can access with `$anything->someAttribute` then if they are declared public.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating default object from empty value in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900701/creating-default-object-from-empty-value-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you don't check for the case when `find_by_id(...)` returns `false` which could cause that warning.