# Warning: Creating default object from empty value (typical solution not solving issue)

Tags: php, object, warnings, php-5.4

**NOTE:** I've read the other topics on stackoverflow about how to solve this issue: 
[Creating default object from empty value in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900701/creating-default-object-from-empty-value-in-php)

For some reason I still get the Warning message: **Creating default object from empty value**

I've tried a few things to fix the warning:

```
$data = new stdClass();
$data->result->complex->first_key = $old_data->result->complex;
```

also tried:

```
$data->result->complex = new stdClass();
$data->result->complex->first_key = $old_data->result->complex;
```

Still get the warning: **Creating default object from empty value** on the line number of the new stdClass() initialization above.

**Desired Outcome:** 
How can I properly initialize the new empty object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to avoid the warning you'll need to pre-create each level:

```
$data = new stdClass();
$data->result = new stdClass();
$data->result->complex = new stdClass();
$data->result->complex->first_key = $old_data->result->complex;
```

Comment: Easiest answer to understand what's going on in the process.

Answer (score 1):

You are still missing "first" empty object

```
$data->result = new stdClass();
```

Whole can be done by:

```
$data = (object)['result' => (object)['complex' => (object)['first_key' => 'value']]];
```

Or by:

```
$data = json_decode(json_encode(['result' => [complex' => ['first_key' => 'value']]]));
```

Comment: Thanks for providing alternate syntax options.