# PHP: Creating default object from empty value

Tags: php, laravel

I am having a problem with this code:

```
$days = array();
$d = new StdClass;
for($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++){
    $day = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-".$i." day"));
    $d->x = $day; //error
    $days[] = $d;
    unset($d);
}
dd($days);
```

Even thought I have declared a new object it shows me error:

> Creating default object from empty value.

How could i possibly resolve this problem?

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: An array full of objects. It's simplified so not only "x" will be an attribute. It worked just perfectly in plain php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating default object from empty value in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900701/creating-default-object-from-empty-value-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, Hope this will help you out. You should define `$d = new StdClass;` with in the loop. For initiating a new object everytime.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/785709)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$days = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++)
{
    $d = new StdClass;
    $day = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-" . $i . " day"));
    $d->x = $day; //error
    $days[] = $d;
    unset($d);
}
print_r($days);
```

Comment: Defining it in the loop did the thing. Thank you. Will mark as an answer after delay