# Creating default object from empty value in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

I try to let my users update their ads and after click on update button i will get this error:

```
ErrorException in AdController.php line 108:
Creating default object from empty value
```

my `AdController` line `108` is:

```
$ad->company_id = Input::get('company_id');
```

And here is the refer line to that code in my form: as you can see `company_id` field is not empty and will pass company `id` number to that field which is the same as `store` method and works perfectly in there but for `update` method returns this error, also when I check my page source codes there is correct company id and isn't empty.

```
{!! Form::model($ads, ['route' => ['company.update', $ads->id], 'method' => "PUT", 'files' => true]) !!}
<input type="hidden" name="company_id" value ="@foreach ($companies as $company){{ $company->id }}@endforeach">

//the rest of the codes

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

any idea why is that?

Comment: @Bhavik cause if i pass only {{ $company->id }} will get `Undefined variable: company`

Comment: you dont have `$ad->company_id` this value

Comment: @Bhavik this is how render in html `<input type="hidden" name="company_id" value ="3">`

Comment: @Rodrane it is a column in ads table and when i save ads for first time works just fine and save company id who published the ads but for update it's issue somehow!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating default object from empty value in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900701/creating-default-object-from-empty-value-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it!

The issue was

```
$ad = Ad::find($id);
```

line before `line 108` which was

```
$ads = Ad::find($id);
```

before

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this:

```
$ad = Ad::where('id',$id)->first();
$ad->company_id = Input::get('company_id');
```

Hope this work for you!