# Warning: Creating default object from empty value to pass value from controller to view in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework2

**my controller file code**

```
public function viewAction(){
   $this->view->title="View Album";
}
```

**my view file code**

```
<?php echo $this->title;?>
```

but value can not access in view file warning given

> **warning**

**Warning: Creating default object from empty value**

Answer (score 1):

First this is not a Zend Framework issue. It is about core PHP.

It is an `E_STRICT` warning which may be enabled in your `error_reporting` ini settings if you are using PHP <= 5.3. But as of PHP 5.4 that error mode changed to `E_WARNING`. You should not disable `E_WARNING` warnings for the development environment.

So when are you getting that warning? You are getting this while you are trying to use an object which has not defined. Therefore, you have to define that object first, you should then use that property.

In ZF, you have `ViewModel()` object which has property overloading feature. To get rid of this warning you would use `$title` thus

```
public function viewAction()
{
    $view = new ViewModel();
    $view->title = "View Album";

    return $view;
}
```

And in your view script

```
<?php echo $this->title; ?>
```

For more details you may check out this [problem and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900701/creating-default-object-from-empty-value-in-php)