# Creating default object from empty value in PHP for $_GET['variable']?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I'm getting

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in drupal devel.module
>
> > backtrace_error_handler( )

due to

```
$CKEditor = $_GET['CKEditor'] ;
```

I already tried defining it beforehand

```
$_GET = new stdClass();
$CKEditor = new stdClass();
```

as per advice on  [Creating default object from empty value in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900701/creating-default-object-from-empty-value-in-php) (can't comment yet)

**Do i need to define $_GET['variable'] differently?**

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks, didn't find this one before and had a good read, tried many ways but didn't get it to work. Unfortunately can't comment yet on answers. I used recommended #1

`$CKEditor = "";
$CKEditor = isset($_GET['CKEditor']) ? $_GET['CKEditor'] : '';`

Comment: would be great to see an example with $_GET for **Undefined offset**
Not sure what I'm doing wrong or missing, appreciate if you or community can help, thanks, learning lots :)