# creating default object from empty value in laravel but working also well?

Tags: php, laravel

i want to update user with below code but problem is that its update balance perfectly but also giving error in LOgs. and i am unable to figureout issue also tried

> findorfail()
>
> ```
> production.ERROR: Creating default object from empty value {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0):
> ```

```
public function updateBalance(){
    $gnl = General::first();
    $deposit = Deposit::where('status', 1)->get();
    foreach($deposit as $de){
                $pack = Package::Where('id',$de->plan)->first();
                $log = Deposit::Where('id',$de->id)->first();

       $percent = $log->amount * $pack->percent/100;
       $repercent = $percent/1440 ; 
      $tup = Track::where('account_id',$de->account_id)->first();
        $tup->balance +=$repercent; //here getting error line
                $tup->save();
    }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating default object from empty value in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900701/creating-default-object-from-empty-value-in-php)

Comment: If the error is where you are indicating, that would seem to indicate that `Track::where()` is returning no results.  You should perhaps check that `$tup` has been created as the expected object before performing the following two lines.

Comment: @PatrickQ but its updatin the balance of user that is mentioned in query as well

Comment: Is this your _exact_ code, copy/pasted with no changes (except for the comment indicating the error line)?

Comment: Your error message appears to be trimmed.  Could you please provide the full error message text?

Comment: @PatrickQ [2019-11-27 17:55:36] production.ERROR: Creating default object from empty value {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Creating default object from empty value at /home/digisffl/public_html/core/app/Http/Controllers/AccountController.php:382)

Comment: yes i am using exact

Comment: Honestly, I'd probably start popping in some `var_dump()`s for pretty much every var and confirming that they're what you expect.  Basic debugging.