# How do I access individual values from JSON data returned from PHP to Javascript using $.post?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have successfully retrieved a response from a PHP file into Javascript, however it is returned as one long string; when I need to put each separate element into a separate place in the HTML.

```
  $.post("includes/skill_scout_1.php", {
      selected_player: selected_transfer_player
      }, function (data, status) {
        $("#transfers-scout-1").html(data);
      });
```

I am looking to do something like this

```
  $.post("includes/skill_scout_1.php", {
      selected_player: selected_transfer_player
      }, function (data, status) {
          var obj = JSON.parse(data);
          $("#transfers-scout-1").html(obj.scout1);
          $("#transfers-scout-2").html(obj.scout2);
          $("#transfers-scout-3").html(obj.scout3);
      }
```

However it returns no data and I get the following error in the web console SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data.

Within the PHP file I have this to return the data to Javascript as JSON:

```
$myObj->scout1 = $scout1;
$myObj->scout2 = $scout2;
$myObj->scout3 = $scout3; 
$myJSON = json_encode($myObj);
echo $myJSON;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

When I try the below #transfer-scout-4 fills with the entire string (as expected), but #transfer-scout-1, #transfer-scout-2 and #transfer-scout-3 are blank.

```
      $.post("includes/skill_scout_1.php", {
  selected_player: selected_transfer_player
  }, function (data, status) {
      $("#transfers-scout-4").html(data);
      var obj = JSON.parse(data);
      $("#transfers-scout-1").html(obj.scout1);
      $("#transfers-scout-2").html(obj.scout2);
      $("#transfers-scout-3").html(obj.scout3);
  
  });
```

Thanks

Comment: Java != JavaScript. Make sure you understand the difference, and then update you question accordingly.

Comment: Anyway it's unclear what the issue is. The code looks like it should probably work. Please explain any debugging you have done which would help us understand precisely what is happening with the data.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Its encouraging that you think the code should work. I'll try some more debugging and post the errors if it still doesn't work.

Comment: The problem has to be in this part:    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
      Do I need to add a line in the header or something to get the parse to work?

Comment: anything after JSON.parse(data) is ignored by the code, even if it is just $("#transfers-scout-2").html(data);   nothing is returned.

Comment: Have you checked your browser's Console for errors? Have you logged the contents of `data` to inspect it?

Comment: contents of data look fine to me    {"position":"Striker","scout1":"is sharp as a razor blade","scout2":"watch out, he'll lose your defenders","scout3":"is good in the air", etc..."scout16":"provides that creative spark"}

Comment: but i get this error   Warning: Creating default object from empty value in C:\xamppone\htdocs\mezzala\includes\skill_scout_1.php on line 600.

Comment: line 600 is this $myObj->position = $detailed_position;

Comment: there are no error in the console - but thanks for pointing out - something I should start using!

Comment: This article: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8900730/5947043 will explain about the "Creating default object from empty value" error. But that isn't affecting your Javascript code really.

Comment: Assuming your HTML is correct then there's nothing obviously wrong with the code. Try without the JSON.parse, in case jquery has already parsed the data for you (it might, if it detects that it's JSON - although that's likely to then result in an error when you try to parse it, but you said there were no errors). Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/1gtk8zj5/1/

Comment: Thanks for you help. It is much appreciated.

Comment: Without the JSON.parse, but with html(data.scout1) I get nothing returned.

Comment: I am now getting this error in the web console   SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: what _is_ the unexpected character? It usually tells you? And what does your code look like now, so I can be sure?

Comment: this is the message in the web console: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data2 mezzala:531:26
    <anonymous> http://localhost/mezzala/:531
    jQuery 4
        fire
        fireWith
        done
        callback

Comment: I can't see where it tells me which character is the problem.

Comment: Current code (trying different things to see what happens):
      
      $.post("includes/skill_scout_1.php", {
      selected_player: selected_transfer_player
      }, function (data, status) {
          $("#transfers-scout-4").html(data);
          $("#transfers-scout-2").html(data.scout2);
          $("#transfers-scout-1").html(data.scout1);
          var obj = JSON.parse(data);
          $("#detailed-position").html(obj.detailed_position);
          $("#transfers-scout-3").html(data.scout3);
      });

Comment: $myObj->scout1 = $scout1; 
$myObj->scout2 = $scout2;  
$myObj->scout3 = $scout3;
$myObj->scout4 = $scout4;
$myObj->scout5 = $scout5;
$myObj->scout6 = $scout6;
$myObj->scout7 = $scout7;
$myObj->scout8 = $scout8;
$myObj->scout9 = $scout9;
$myObj->scout10 = $scout10;
$myObj->scout11 = $scout11;
$myObj->scout12 = $scout12;
$myObj->scout13 = $scout13;
$myObj->scout14 = $scout14;
$myObj->scout15 = $scout15;
$myObj->scout16 = $scout16;

$myJSON = json_encode($myObj);
echo $myJSON;

Comment: _“I can't see where it tells me which character is the problem.”_ - open your browser dev tools, go to the network panel, inspect the request. Check what the actual response was. Most likely it will start with something like `<Doctype>` or `<html>`, because your PHP script contained a fatal error, so that your web server returned the error document for a 500 Internal Server Error instead. And anything starting with those kind of characters, is obviously not valid JSON.

Comment: Cheers, never used that network tab before. Looks like it will come in useful.