# Error message: Creating default object from empty value

Tags: php, laravel

Facing this error message but not sure what is wrong with it? Tried the solutions at StackOverflow and other forums but didn't work either.

The error is at line $review->title=$request->title;

```
    public function updateReview(Request $request)
    {
    // dd($request->all());

    $review = Review::find($request->id);
    $review->id=$request->id;
    $review->title=$request->title;
    $review->review=$request->review;
    $review->rating=$request->rating;

    $review->save(); 

    return redirect('/');
    
    }
```

A dd($request->all()); returns the following:

```
array:5 [▼
  "id" => "3"
  "title" => "User 3 has updated title"
  "review" => "User 4 just updated review"
  "rating" => "5"
  "_token" => "pGFVAzHNg7HmXbkMXylxcM6biqaGnwFmsxjsrTgl"
]
```

And these are my routes:

```
Route::get('/edit_review/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\UserController@editReview');
Route::post('/update', 'App\Http\Controllers\UserController@updateReview')->middleware('user');
```

Comment: What is the output of `dd($request->all());`?

Comment: array:4 [▼
  "title" => "This is an updated Title"
  "review" => "I am updating the Review"
  "rating" => "5"
  "_token" => "Dyjm8Tis2MhpMsjKUkMI8Tfxv3rC6DK2OobMwmK7"
]

Comment: Please post code as text with the appropriate markup rather than images.

Comment: The error is not about what $request contains, but about $review not being an object in the first place - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900701/creating-default-object-from-empty-value-in-php

Comment: this line cause the error `$review->title` because find method `find($request->id)`  not matched with your query, so us `findOrFail()` instead of `find()`

Comment: I already posted an answer about the error, because `$request->id` returns null. if you see the `dd($request->all());` output, there are no any `id` on the output. So there is no  `$request->id`

Comment: there is a `$id` you passed, can you post the route code here, so that I can fix your code

Comment: @sufyanahmad hello, are you still facing the same issue?

Comment: @sta So far it's ok. Many thanks for the help.

Comment: @suftanhmad please mark this,answer as accepted if it helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting this error `Warning: Creating default object from empty value` because `$review->title` returns `false`.

`find()` takes an id and returns a single model. If no matching model exist, it returns `null`.

You can use  `findOrFail()` instead of `find()`, if the record not matched then `findOrFail()` will throw a 404 error :

```
$review = Review::findOrFail($request->id);
```

I think you've missed to define a parameter on your function, that passes with your route, probaby its `{id}` :

```
public function updateReview(Request $request, $id)
{  
    $review = Review::findOrFail($id); 
    //... 
}
```