# When trying to upload image path to database I get this error "Creating default object from empty value"

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, filepath, image-upload

I keep getting this error  "Creating default object from empty value" whenever I try uploading profile image when registering user, what I want to do is to upload to the image path "profile-photos/PP_1637044275.jpg" to the database, not the image name, any help will be appreciated.

**This is the Controller/action class**

```
  class CreateNewUser implements CreatesNewUsers
 {
    use PasswordValidationRules;

  /**
 * Validate and create a newly registered user.
 *
 * @param  array  $input
 * @return \App\Models\User
 */
public function create(array $input)
{

    $request = request();

    //Handle profile photo Upload
    if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {
        // Get filename with extention 
        $filenamewithExt = $request->file('photo')->getClientOriginalName();
        // Get just filename
        $filename = pathinfo($filenamewithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        // Get just Extention
        $extention = $request->file('photo')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        // Filename to store
        $filenameToStore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extention;
        // Upload Image
        $path = $request->file('photo')->storeAs('profile-photos', 
        $filenameToStore);

        $user = new User;
        $user->profile_photo_path = $path;
       

    }

    
 
    if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {
        
        $user->profile_photo_path = $path;
  
       
    }
```

**This is the View**

```
     <!-- PROFILE INFO -->
    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <div x-show.transition.in="step === 1">
    <div class="mb-5 text-center">
    <div class="mx-auto w-32 h-32 mb-2 border rounded-full relative bg-gray-100 mb-4 
    shadow-inset">
      <img id="image" class="object-cover w-full h-32 rounded-full" :src="image" />
    </div>

    <label
      for="fileInput"
      type="button"
      class="cursor-pointer inine-flex justify-between items-center focus:outline-none 
      border py-2 px-4 rounded-lg shadow-sm text-left text-gray-600 bg-white hover:bg- 
      gray-100 font-medium"
    >
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="inline-flex flex-shrink-0 w-6 h-6 - 
       mt-1 mr-1" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" 
        stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="24" height="24" stroke="none"></rect>
        <path d="M5 7h1a2 2 0 0 0 2 -2a1 1 0 0 1 1 -1h6a1 1 0 0 1 1 1a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h1a2 
      2 0 0 1 2 2v9a2 2 0 0 1 -2 2h-14a2 2 0 0 1 -2 -2v-9a2 2 0 0 1 2 -2" />
        <circle cx="12" cy="13" r="3" />
      </svg>
      Browse Photo
    </label>

    <div class="mx-auto w-48 text-gray-500 text-xs text-center mt-1">Click to add 
    profile picture</div>

    <input name="photo" id="fileInput" accept="image/*" class="hidden" type="file" 
    @change="let file = document.getElementById('fileInput').files[0];
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = (e) => image = e.target.result;
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);">
   </div>
```

Comment: the error line? this OP can be considered as a duplicate for [Creating default object from empty value in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900701/creating-default-object-from-empty-value-in-php)

Comment: @hassan It may be because of the title, BUT IT IS NOT DUPLICATE. Completely different case

Comment: how could we know while there are no debugging details? please add it to make it easier.

Comment: @hassan debugging details like ?

Answer (score 1):

Your error may be triggered by this line:

```
   if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {
     
        $user->profile_photo_path = $path;
      
    }
```

Try removing this as you've already saved the `profile_photo_path` earlier and that your $user variable may be undefined here.

EDIT: If you're saving the image to your public disk, you can just do this:

```
$user->profile_photo_path = 'profile-photos/'.$filenameToStore;
```

Then show the image on your blade view by

```
<img src="{{asset($user->profile_photo_path)}}">
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Sure thing. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the problem, the intention was to save the image/profile photo to the database with the path like profile-photo/image-name not just the image/filename

```
   if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {
    // Get filename with extention 
    $ImageNameWithExt = $request->file('photo')->getClientOriginalName();
    // Get just filename
    $ImageName = pathinfo($ImageNameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    // Get just Extention
    $Extentions = $request->file('photo')->getClientOriginalExtension();
    // Filename to store
    $filenameToStore = $ImageName.'_'.time().'.'.$Extentions;
    // Upload Image
    $paths = $request->file('photo')->storeAs('public/profile-photos', 
    $filenameToStore);

    $path = 'profile-photos';
    $user = new User;
    $user->profile_photo_path =  $path . '/' . $filenameToStore;


}

        $imageWithPath = $user->profile_photo_path;

        $user =  User::create([
        'profile_photo_path'=> $imageWithPath,
        'username'          => $input['username'],
```