# Constructing classes php

Tags: php, class, constructor

Cannot find docs describing what is the difference between

```
$object = new myClass();
```

and

```
$object = new myClass;
```

Whats the point ?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873111/instantiate-a-class-with-or-without-parentheses

Comment: actually duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945989/php-class-instantiation-to-use-or-not-to-use-the-parentheses

Comment: to pass parameters to constructor. thanks