# How to define this kind of php function?

Tags: php, function, class

I saw some sample php scripts can use a function after one another, but I can't find how to write script like that.

When I write the php script:

```
class apple {
  function banana() {
    echo 'Hi!';
  }
}
```

It looks like this when I want to call the function `banana`:

```
$apple = new apple;
$apple->banana();
```

What if I want to call a function right after the previous one, like this:

> **$apple->banana()->orange()**

I've tried to put an function inside another, but it returns with error.
How can I write the script like this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP method chaining?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724112/php-method-chaining)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code is to improve your method chaining,

```
    <?php

    class Fruits
    {
        public function banana()
        {
            echo 'Hi i am banana!'.'<br>';
            return $this;
        }

        public function orange()
        {
            echo 'Hi i am orange!'.'<br>';
            return $this;
        }

        public function __call($mName,$mValues)
        {
            echo 'Hi i am '.$mName.'!'.'<br>';
            return $this;
        }
    }

    $fruits = new Fruits();
    $fruits->banana()->orange()->grape()->avocado();
```

Comment: What is `$mValues` mean?

Comment: @timo `$mValues` is an array of arguments passed to the undefined method.

Comment: @timo if you pass arguments to the method `avocado('one','two')` those arguments will be stored in `$mValues` array.

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this:

```
class apple {
  public function banana() {
    echo 'Hi!';
    return $this;
  }
  public function orange() {
      echo 'Hi from orange';
      return $this;
  }
}

$apple = new apple;
$apple->banana()->orange();
```

This is a shortcut to something like this:

```
$apple = new apple;
$same_apple = $apple->banana();
// $apple and $same_apple are the same thing here.
$still_the_same_apple = $same_apple->orange();
```

In the end, $apple and $still_the_same_apple are the same instance you created in the first place.

Comment: What's the difference of `$apple = new apple;` and `$apple = new apple();`?

Comment: There is no difference if you don't want to supply constructor arguments.  There is a discussion about this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873111/instantiate-a-class-with-or-without-parentheses