# Class instantiation with and without parantheses

Tags: python, class

Consider the following:

```
class car:
    pass
tesla=car()
```

When I do `type(tesla)`, this gives `__main__.car`, as I expect.
But if I have:

```
class car:
    pass
tesla=car
```

then `type(car)` gives `type`.

From another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873111/instantiate-a-class-with-or-without-parentheses) on SO, it really shouldn't matter how I instantiate the class. But clearly as we see here, the type of the object is different. I am an absolute beginner to python, could you please let me know what is going on here.

Thanks!

Comment: You should not try to use PHP syntax with python. Your SO-link is about PHP.

Comment: `car()` is an instance of `car`, which is a `type`... just like it says!

Comment: `tesla=car` does not instantiate anything. Your link is to a question regarding PHP. PHP is not Python

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second case, you're not instantiating the class, just giving it another name, `tesla`. The parentheses are required for instantiation.