# When to add brackets after new class name?

Tags: php, class

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP class instantiation. To use or not to use the parenthesis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945989/php-class-instantiation-to-use-or-not-to-use-the-parenthesis)
>   [Omission of brackets and parameter-less object constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142705/omission-of-brackets-and-parameter-less-object-constructors)

With or without the brackets, the new Class seems not bother. So, I doubt what's the usage of the brackets `()`. I searched php manual, didn't get it. Could anybody explain?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The purpose of the brackets is for you to enter any arguments that your constructor may accept.

```
class Example{

    private $str;

    public function __construct($str){
        $this->str = $str;
    }

    public function output(){
        echo $this->str;
    }

}

$ex = new Example; // missing argument error
$ex = new Example('Something');
$ex->output(); // echos "Something"
```

If your class constructor does not accept any arguments, you may leave the brackets out. For good code sake, I always keep the brackets, whether or not the constructor accepts any argument.

Most coders coming from C# or Java background would keep the parenthesis as it is more familar to them.

Comment: I don't see why i was downvoted trying to answer the asker's question.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer and other experts that helped me on my php journey. Sometimes it's hard to understand why got down vote without a tip pointing any mistake. I will keep the question open for a little while to see if the person who vote down your answer has anything else to say.

Comment: I did not downvote but i would argue its good code to omit them: less cruft.

Comment: I see, Gordon, the arrow is for voting. For different opinion, you can post a new answer. Thanks for explain anyway :-)

Comment: @Jenny I've already answered this in one of the linked duplicates