# Am I calling this class wrong?

Tags: php

I have this code in a file named `server.class.php`:

```
class server
{

function addPlayer($player)
    {
      //Stuff
    }
}
```

Then, I have this in a file called `send.php`. These are lines 38-40:

```
require('/var/www/server/apply/server.class.php');
$server = new server;
$server->addPlayer($_POST['IGN']);
```

However, I get this error when I visit my page (Php.ini is set to show all errors):

> **Fatal error**: Class 'server' not found in **/var/www/server/apply/send.php** on line **39**

Line 39 is `$server = new server;`

What am I doing wrong? I have verified that the class file is in `/var/www/server/apply/server.class.php`.

Comment: Put an `echo` statement in `server.class.php` to verify if the file has been correctly included.

Comment: @Antony the file would stop if it hadn't been included, since he's used "require()"

Comment: Or better yet, put `error_reporting(-1);` at the top of your script.

Comment: @Antony As it is the entire server.class.php file is printed to the webpage before the error.

Comment: @chipperyman573 try starting the file with `<?php`. LOL

Comment: @chipperyman573 add <?php to the start of your code :)

Comment: @Mike I do already. Without lines 38-40 the website loads fine

Comment: @chipperyman573 you don't in server.class.php

Comment: @chipperyman573 put it at the start of server.class.php

Comment: lol @Mike - damn your fast fingers!

Comment: Ohhh..... The tutorial I followed (just started learning two days ago) never mentioned it.

Comment: @chipperyman573 easy mistake to make - we've all been there!

Comment: Class_exists (server) what you getting ...?

Comment: @chipperyman573 you don't need the `?>` tag at the end of your files. In fact, it is discouraged.

Comment: @Mike Thanks, I removed it. What's the point of it if it's not supposed to be used?

Comment: @Mike Agreed. If you have invisible characters after it, you might run into unexpected errors with headers.

Comment: Hard to find a tutorial that's going to tell you everything, especially when it comes to using classes. It's 'assumed" the person behind the wheel, already knows a few things before turning the key ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- [It is?](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)

Comment: @chipperyman573 When using `?>` anything after it will be echoed to the browser. Sometimes this is desired, like `?> <some_html_stuff /> <?php`, but at the end of the file it is discouraged in case you accidentally put some white space characters after it (which is very easy to do). This could mess your whole website up because you won't be able to send any more HTTP headers after anything has been echoed to the browser.

Comment: Except `PHP.net` ;-) @Daedalus lol

Answer (score 0):

$server = new server()

Missed the brackets

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945989/php-class-instantiation-to-use-or-not-to-use-the-parentheses :D

Comment: *"If the constructor doesn't take any parameters I leave them out too"* --- as said in the first comment of the accepted answer in the link you provided. @DaveChen