# Why can't I call to a function in a file that's included in the header?

Tags: php, include

I'm using Wordpress with a custom theme.

At the top of the header.php of the theme I've got a Mobile Detect script.

```
require_once '/extras/Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect;
```

Then further down the header.php page I have a line that checks if the user is on a Mobile, and displays different content accordingly.

```
if ($detect->isMobile()) { echo "Premium"; } else { echo variable('prem_no'); }
```

However, in a further included PHP file further down the page, when I try to use the same script:

```
if ($detect->isMobile()) { echo "Find a psychic"; } else { echo "Our Psychic Readers"; }
```

I get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function isMobile() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\clairvoyant\extras\reader-categories.php on line 1

How can I make it so that a file required or included in the header.php file, can be referenced to throughout the rest of the page files?

I'm a bit confused between include, include_once, require and require_once, so can someone help clear that up?

Answer (score 2):

Not too many differences between `require` and `include` but the main point is  with `require` the file must exist or you get an error while include is optional.

and the `_once` is to make sure you don't include it more than `once`.

---

> However, in a further included PHP file further down the page, when I
>   try to use the same script I get this error...

This sounds like `$detect` is not the same object for example

```
require_once '/extras/Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect;
if ($detect->isMobile()) { echo "Premium"; }//Good
....
$detect['mobile'] = 'iPhone';
if ($detect->isMobile()) { echo "Find a psychic"; }//Bad
```

Comment: That doesn't make any difference, the error is still produced. And it doesn't say in the guide to use the parentheses (https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect/wiki/Code-examples)

Comment: Parentheses are optional in PHP for non-parameterized constructors, http://stackoverflow.com/q/1945989/231316

Comment: @LeeCollings how about using `include '/extras/Mobile_Detect.php';` instead of `require_once`

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that somewhere along the lines `$detect` is being reset to something else. Do a search for all instances of `$detect` and look for something that's using a single equals instead of a double or triple. It could also be another include somewhere that's resetting it.

If the variable `$detect` flat out didn't exist you would have received a different notice, `Undefined variable: detect`.

If `$detect` were a valid object but the method no longer existed you would have received `Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mobile_Detect::isMobile`.

However your error says that the variable that you are working with is not an object and therefor can't have a member function in the first place.