# Can't call function from another file

Tags: php, oop

I'm trying to learn OOP through experimenting. As a start I building a small calendar app.
I have a crud.php file with several functions inside Crud class. 
I can't call function from this file anyway. What mistake I made here?

PS: The function works if called inside the same file.

crud.php

```
class Crud {
    public $id;
    private $date_in;
    private $date_out;

    public function setId ($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function setDates ($date_in, $date_out) {
        $this->date_in = $date_in;
        $this->date_out = $date_out;
    }
    public function getId () {
        return $this->id;
    }
    public function getDateIn () {
        return $this->date_in;
    }
    public function getDateOut (){
        return $this->date_out;
    }
    public function add () {
    $datein = $this->getDateIn();
    $dateout = $this->getDateOut();
    include "../libs/db_con.php";
    $q = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO dates (date_in, date_out) VALUES (?,?);");
    $q->execute(array($datein,$dateout));

}

    public function delete ($id) {
        include "../libs/db_con.php";
        $q = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM dates WHERE id = ?;");
        $q->execute(array($id));
    }

    public function test() {
        var_dump(get_object_vars($this));
    }
}
```

add.php

```
include "actions/crud.php";
    $crud = new Crud;
        $crud->setDates("204", "23");
        $crud->add();
```

Comment: your include path is correct right? have you enabled PHP_ERROR reporting ?

Comment: Check the error logs.

Comment: Does it throw you any errors, and if so, which ones?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it will help somebody in the future learning OOP.

The problem was that include paths were set to location relevant for crud.php not for files there were called in (add.php which was one folder up).

Answer (score 0):

use     `$crud = new Crud();` This is proper way.

For more Check **[HERE](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)**

You missed `()` round brackets.

Comment: It does not matter if you use $crud = new Crud; or $crud = new Crud(); For more information view http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945989/php-class-instantiation-to-use-or-not-to-use-the-parentheses